# Different AlertDialog icon for GingerBread and ICS/JB

Tags: android, themes, android-alertdialog, android-theme

I am using ABS custom theme. For the AlertDialog shown below, the icon I am using is from the holo_light pack. As you can see, for GingerBread, the dialog's background colour is black, so for GB I need to use the holo_dark icon. So, how can I fix it so that when the black dialog of GB comes up, the icon it uses is from the holo_dark pack, while for the lighter dialog of HoneyComb and up, it uses the holo_light icon?

Or can it be done such that the GB dialog's background colour is made lighter like that in ICS or JB?

**JellyBean** AlertDialog:

[image]

---

**GingerBread** AlertDialog:

[image]

---

**EDIT:** Or is there any way to change the black coloured dialog of GB to a white one?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the current Android version at runtime like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 0x00000009 /*Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD*/){...}
```

Then you can choose the theme based on it.

Comment: That works. But is there any way to change to black dialog to GB to a white one?

Comment: Have you tried forcing your chosen theme with the theme proprerty in the application tag of your manifest file? For example:android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" to force the black theme and no title bar.